# In Python 3 (under Pydev) how to correctly write imports within packages

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

Similar questions have been asked a number of times, but none of the suggested solutions work (satisfactory) in my case.

I have a Python 3 project with a structure like so:

```
├── project1
│   ├── package
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── test1.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── module1.py
│   │   └── module2.py
│   └── setup.py
```

I have `package` listed as source folder in `PYTHONPATH` (in Eclipse).

Everything works fine inside the project, i.e.:

- In `tests\test1.py` doing `import module1` **works**
- In `module2.py` both `from module1 import foo` or simply `import module1` **work**

**However**, when I package my code and install it using `pip` I start getting `ImportError`.

If in `project2` I try to `import module2` or `from module2 import foo` I get an error on the import that `module2` does from `module1`.
For the imports in `project2` to work I need to change the import in `module2` to be `from package.module1 import foo` or `import package.module2`. This makes `project1` to throw import errors.
There are similar problems with `test1.py`.

I can in Eclipse add the folder of `project1` to `PYTHONPATH` and that solves the **runtime** error, but I still see compilation errors in PyDev.

Is there any way to write the imports or define the PYTHONPATH so Python 3 will find the imported modules/methods in all cases?
I am emphasizing Python 3 because I have a project with the same structure (as far as I can tell) under Python 2 which works well with the imports defined as `import .module1` (this throws an error for Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the following:

- Changed all imports to full path, i.e. `package.module[.method]`
- Added `package` to `PYTHONPATH`
- **Removed** `package.module` folder from the `PYTHONPATH`

The first two changes are enough for the code to run properly.
The last bullet causes PyDev to stop displaying errors.